# If condition and mysql connection isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement

I have a code that connects to my database and should display the text. If the id isn't existing it should redirect me.

```
include ('design.php');
include ('mysqli/opendb.php');
if(empty($_GET['id']))
{
 header("Location:index.php");
}

  $stmt=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT titel, text, DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%d. %m. %Y'), autor FROM news WHERE id = ?");
   $stmt->bind_param("i",$_GET['id']);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->bind_result($titel, $text, $datum, $autor);
   $stmt->fetch();
    var_dump($titel); //Result or NULL
   if(empty($titel));  // <-- isn't working / execute when $titel has a value and when it's NULL
   {  
    die(header("Location:index.php"));
   }
```

My SQL query is working, I get my title etc. or if the id isn't existing I get a NULL but my if isnt. It executes as well as I get a result and I dont get on. And I have no idea why.

The code is from an article display. If the article doesn't exist I should be redirected to the startpage.

(I know this code is not safe from SQL injections, but the security of the code is outside the scope of this question.)

Comment: I'd put the mysql code inside an "else" block. The redirect doesn't work if you add other outputs.

Comment: `theabovepage.php?id=somerandomstring` what should happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your expectation is that the script terminates in case the id is not given, replace your first header() call in line 5 with the following:

```
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
```

`header()` itself is just setting the HTTP header and does not affect the code flow.

See http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php for documentation.

And as for the "if": **There is a semicolon after it - that's why it is not working.**

Comment: thats why I have my header() inside a die(). And where is my second header?

Comment: @Lithilion your 1st header is not inside die()

Comment: The second one is in line 5.

Comment: Sorry my fault. But thats not the problem. My If isnt working properly

Comment: There is a semicolon after your if() - that's why it is not working.

Comment: ^thats the right answser because `die(header...);` actualy works.. Even if it looks odd